# Line Chart using Arrays instead of Range

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, charts

So I have a code that generates 3 One-Dimensional Arrays (30 elements each). First array has dates (x values) and other 2 arrays have numbers (1 is sales from company K 2 is sales from company M on the day). Now I want to use VBA to use these arrays as the series. I've come across a simple code and tried to use it for my purposes... but this is my first time using charts in vba and i never was great with making charts to begin with. Please help!

You can assume I have `Date`, `Sales_K` and `Sales_M` as arrays with indexes going from 1 to 30 (30 entries)

```
Dim myChart As Chart

Dim mySeries As Series

Set myChart = Charts.Add

Set myChart = myChart.Location(Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Sheet1")
```

'Kinda lost here I dont know how to activate the chart or if theres an important difference between defining a "chart" and a "chartObject"

```
Set myChart = ActiveChart  

Set mySeries = myChart.SeriesCollection(1)


series.xvalues = Date

series.values = Sales_K 'How do I add Sales_M y value series??
```

Please keep it as simple as possible. I tried watching some youtube videos on charts but they start going into chartObjects using the "Parent" property of charts... all I want is to create a line chart with 2 lines and date as the x values by using arrays.

Comment: First start before anything is to not use the reserved word Date as your array name. Date is a VBA function which rerutns the current date. So use myDate or something else...

Answer (score 0):

You can add another series via the newSeries method as shown below. You can also re-use the same XValues if you wish.

A ChartObject is the placeholder object, and the Chart contains all the detail(simple way of putting it).

```
Public Sub makeChart()

  Dim ch As Chart
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant, arr3 As Variant
  Dim ser As Series, ser2 As Series

  Set ws = Sheet5
  Set ch = ws.chartObjects.Add(Left:=100, Top:=100, Width:=500, Height:=400).Chart
  ch.ChartType = xlLine

  arr1 = Array(10, 15, 12, 25, 35, 20)
  arr2 = Array(17, 33, 20, 45, 11, 40)
  'arr3 = Array("01/05/2016", "02/05/2016", "03/05/2016", "04/05/2016", "05/05/2016", "06/05/2016")
  arr3 = Array(DateValue("01/05/2016"), DateValue("02/05/2016"), DateValue("03/05/2016"), _
              DateValue("04/05/2016"), DateValue("05/05/2016"), DateValue("06/05/2016"))

  Set ser = ch.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
  ser.XValues = arr3
  ser.Values = arr1
  Set ser2 = ch.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
  ser2.Values = arr2

End Sub
```